# How to fix CAPS LOCK syncing in NoMachine?

Tags: server, client, remote-desktop, capslock, nomachine

I have searched everywhere for a fix to the keyboard CAPS LOCK bug for NoMachine, but I cannot seem to find any.

The issue is that the CAPS LOCK is acting extra weird where it turns itself on and off at irregular times (even when not requested), not turning at all, or it may get stuck at one state.

I am using both of client/server on Mac OS High Sierra  and Windows 10, and I tried connecting between Mac-Windows, Windows-Mac, and even Windows-Windows with another Windows 10 device, and the issue still persists. I assume this issue happens on Linux client/server as well.

Answer (score 2):

Although the [bug report](https://www.nomachine.com/TR11P08979) that [NoMachiner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3070109/nomachiner) mentioned in a comment has been closed with the comment "Resolved in version 6.10.12 released on 2020-05-12.", this issue still seems to be present in version 6.11.2, although it doesn't happen every time.

The way I fix it is to give focus to any application other than NoMachine, toggle the caps lock and then return to NoMachine. It seems that for some reason, while NoMachine has focus toggling Capslock will always toggle it, but when NoMachine doesn't have focus, it will only toggle the capslock if the state has changed. Very strange, and very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

There have been some problems, in the past, due to the inheritance of some keyboard code from X11, but, as far as I know, no such problems exist, in the current version. Are you using a reasonably recent version? The latest is 6.3.6.

Comment: The problem still exists (I downloaded the last version from the main website just yesterday). However, if I do not use CAPS LOCK on, say, Windows 10 lock screen, the bug won't happen, and the CAPS LOCK will work just fine.

Comment: It seems your specific issue affecting the CAPS LOCK on Windows 10 has been reported. (When capslock is enabled whilst the user is connected to the login/lock screen, capslock goes out of sync).  A useful link to the bug report: nomachine.com/TR11P08979

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by following these instructions on ArchLinux wiki ([Map_scancodes_to_keycodes](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Map_scancodes_to_keycodes)):

- Created the file `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/90-block-sleep.hwdb` and added the following lines:

  ```
   evdev:atkbd:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:svn*:pn*:pvr*
   KEYBOARD_KEY_3a=leftctrl
  ```
- Next run:

  `$ sudo systemd-hwdb update`

  `$ sudo udevadm trigger`

Maybe you need adapt the solution to your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

1. Disconnect noMachine
2. Toggle the Caps Lock outside of noMachine
3. Re-connect noMachine

This worked for me.